# Why use meta tag Content-Style-Type for external css?

Tags: html

Browsing through the source code of Microsoft's sample StockTrader application, I found this snippet in all aspx files:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
<title>.NET StockTrader Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StockTrader.css" type="text/css" />
```

Why have the meta tag when the link tag says it all? Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, HTML5 validator gags on it.

Comment: I noticed that firefox alone was misrendering some of my pages, digging deeper I found I had this meta tag in my <head> but had a typo in the content parameter. It seems firefox is the only browser that cares!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "Content-Style-Type" meta tag is used to set the *default* style type for the document.  In practice, this doesn't seem that useful, as most people specifically specify the style types whenever they are used, such as in the `<link>` tag in your question.  This particular declaration seems extra redundant as well.  [According to the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.1):

> User agents should determine the
>   default style sheet language for a
>   document according to the following
>   steps (highest to lowest priority):
>
> 1. If any META declarations specify the "Content-Style-Type", the last one
>      in the character stream determines the
>      default style sheet language.
> 2. Otherwise, if any HTTP headers specify the "Content-Style-Type", the
>      last one in the character stream
>      determines the default style sheet
>      language.
> 3. Otherwise, the default style sheet language is "text/css".

So theoretically, using "Content-Style-Type" to set the default to "text/css" is just overriding what the browser would have assumed anyway, although maybe it's insurance against a rogue web server that might try to set something in the HTTP headers.

It's probably generated in an enthusiastic attempt to be standards compliant.

*Quick edit note*:  That W3 document I linked to actually claims that a document that has elements which use a *style* attribute without defining a default style sheet language is an incorrect document.  I've never seen this come up as an issue in a validator before however.

Comment: Microsoft... "enthusiastic attempt to be standards compliant"... am I missing something? hehe. +1 Great answer.

Comment: The validator wouldn't raise it as an issue - it isn't something that can be expressed in a DTD. Validity is only a subset of conformance.

Answer (score 22):

The reason why you in theory need a `Content-Style-Type` setting is for inline style attributes:

```
<div style="color: red;">
```

What styling language is that in? Unlike with `<style>` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags there is no `type` attribute mechanism to tell the browser what language that is: hence the document-global Content-Style-Type.

The same applies to `Content-Script-Type` and inline event handler attributes:

```
<div onclick='alert("hello")'>
```

What language is that? It's actually equally valid in JavaScript and VBScript; in IE it could be either. In theory, you should give the browser a `Content-Script-Type` header/meta to tell it. Even with plain old JavaScript, you might want to change the dialect by setting type parameters such as `text/javascript;version=1.6` or `e4x=1` (if you wanted to use E4X XML literals, which you don't because they're a vile mistake).

In practice, none of this is of any use whatsoever, since the default CSS is the only style language you can actually use, many browsers don't pay any attention to `Content-Style-Type` anyway, and no browser pays any attention to `Content-Script-Type`.

(Ah well, who needs inline style and event handler attributes anyway?)

Comment: I have seen the similar post before but never got this response .. +1

here is an old post .. expects almost similar answer ..(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939949/html-do-we-really-need-different-doctypes)

Answer (score 3):

It's a waste of bandwidth. Nobody actually does anything with it. (It's so useless it isn't even included in HTML5.)

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Style-Type meta tag indicates the default style sheet language. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#default-style

If you specify the type attribute on every link tag you don't need the meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it doesn't make a difference, as CSS is assumed to be used by all the major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this sets the default for both inline styles and links. This falls into the category of things that may not be needed but should be included. It is defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/styles.html#default-style and other posters have noted that major browsers all assume it. But it should still be added because browsers are not the only consumers of HTML files. They can be imported into or processed by other programs who may follow the specs more carefully than the browsers.